# Is it possible to do prototype-based programming in Scala?

Tags: oop, scala, prototype

Is it possible to do prototype-based programming in Scala?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please describe your question more precisely? If you want to know whether Scala is prototype-based language like Io or JavaScript, then answer is no. In Scala you have Classes that are blueprints for new objects and they are mandatory. So you can't create object without such blueprint.

Answer (score 4):

I have to disagree with Easy Angel... Scala objects do not need classes (they still all have a type... but that is not the same). Its perfectly ok to write

```
val martin = new { 
  val name = "Martin"
  val surname = "Ring"
  def age = Calendar.getInstance.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1986
}
```

also thanks to structural typing you can write functions for these objects:

```
def printPerson(person: { def name: String; def age: Int }) = 
  println("%s (%d)".format(person.name, person.age))
```

you can call `printPerson(martin)` and it will print out `Martin (25)`

So no need for classes or traits if you really want that.

However prototype-based programming is still not supported by the language as it (imho) is not possible to clone and extend objects with anonymous type. I guess you could write functions to do that... but they would require massive use of reflection and thus there is no native lanugage support..

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with EasyAngel, depending on how you want to use a prototype mechanism, you may be able to achieve similar goals with Scala mechanisms.  For example, you can define a trait that can be mixedin to a more generic class.

In some ways this is more powerful than prototype object generation, because you can mix and match a variety of potentially relevant traits.  You can also customize and extend them from within a target subclass.

Further clarifying your question will allow more focused answers.

Comment: From my point of view most power of prototype based languages comes from absence of classes or likes. I think this interesting InfoQ video is relevant to this topic: [Classes Are Premature Optimization](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Classes-Are-Premature-Optimization). I think [autoproxy Scala compiler plugin](https://github.com/scala-incubator/autoproxy-plugin) (it also can be referenced as dynamic mixin) can be even more suitable in this case.

Comment: I appreciate both the presentation and the software description.  However, IMO we need both.  Ideal (abstract) typification and prototype (empirical) generalization each contribute to conceptual (and representational) economy.  How would the absence of one contribute to the contribution of the other?

Comment: Who is easy angel?